# Python argparse store_true and store optional option in one argument

Tags: python, optional-parameters, argparse

I need to recognise if was given argument alone or with optional string or neither

```
parser.add_argument(???)
options = parser.parse_args()
```

so

```
./prog.py --arg
```

should store `''` into options.arg,

```
./prog.py --arg=lol
```

stores `'lol'` into options.arg and

```
./prog.py
```

left options.arg as `None`

now I have:

```
parser.add_argument("--arg", nargs="?",type=str,dest="arg")
```

but when I run myprogram as `./prog.py --arg` options.arg remains `None`. Only way to recognise --arg was given is run it as `./prog.py --arg=` and this is problem for me.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between `''` and `None`? `not ''` and `not None` both evaluate to `True`. It sounds like you have bigger problems than just this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- This is a duplicate, but FWIW, there's a [nicer answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16041243/748858) contributed to this one ... We've both been ninja'd by Evert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`const`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#const) keyword:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--arg", nargs="?", type=str, dest="arg", const="")
print(parser.parse_args([]))
print(parser.parse_args(['--arg']))
print(parser.parse_args(['--arg=lol']))
```

results in

```
Namespace(arg=None)
Namespace(arg='')
Namespace(arg='lol')
```

Comment: Well now, this is fantastic.  and it's even [documented behavior](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#const)  (+1)

Comment: Great thx. Now i see i missed const when i was studiyng http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Comment: @mgilson: thanks for the documentation pointer. Forgot to put that one in. And no, I had no intention to ninja answers ;-).

Comment: I'm actually happy about it.  I learned something new today.

Comment: I use it like this `parser.add_argument("-a", nargs="?", const=True, default=False)`. `[] => False`, `['-a'] => True`, `['-a', 'asdf'] => asdf`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a custom action:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
class ArgAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string=None):
        if values:
            setattr(namespace,self.dest,values)
        else:
            setattr(namespace,self.dest,'')

parser.add_argument("--arg",nargs='?',action=ArgAction,dest="arg")
print parser.parse_args("--arg".split())
print parser.parse_args("--arg=foo".split())
```